# How to listen to an element in the DOM after its ajax request completes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a list in WordPress and every time I click the element that has a `class=woof_radio_label` inside the list it will trigger an ajax request.

```
<ul class="woof_list woof_list_radio">
   <li class="woof_radio_label"><label class="woof_radio_label">Product 1</label></li>
   <li class="woof_radio_label"><label class="woof_radio_label">Product 2</label></li>
   <li class="woof_radio_label"><label class="woof_radio_label">Product 3</label></li>
</ul>
```

**Current jquery code**:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(function() {

    j(document).on('click', '.woof_list_radio > li .woof_radio_label', function(e) {


    });

});


j(document).ajaxComplete(function() {

    j('#woof_results_by_ajax').addClass('woof-results-sh');

});
```

The problem that I see with the code above is that ajaxComplete is called for any element that has an ajax request. `j(document).ajaxComplete()` is also called even on page load when there are any scripts that must execute ajax.

Do you know how can I just listen to `class="woof_radio_label"` that triggered an ajax request? So I can execute `j('#woof_results_by_ajax').addClass('woof-results-sh');`

**Note**: I don't have control to the ajax request because it is generated a by a 3rd party plugin

Comment: What is the reason for calling `j('#woof_results_by_ajax').addClass('woof-results-sh');` on ajaxComplete rather than doing it where the 'completed' console log is?

Comment: @nipuna777 I don't really have a control to the ajax request when the label is clicked because it is generated by a 3rd party plugin. Do you know how can I just listen to the element?

Comment: You possibly need [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with the updated code below:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(function() {
  j(document).on('click', '.woof_list_radio > li .woof_radio_label', function(e) {
    j(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
      j('#woof_results_by_ajax').addClass('woof-results-sh');
    });
  });
});
```

I loaded the ajaxComplete() after a particular click action. I'm not sure if this is the best way but it works for my situation.